# add a class in AJAX if a returned value is true

Tags: jquery, ajax

Afternoon,
I would like to know how i can add a class depending on the returned value from a web service.

```
$.each(result, function (index, res) {
            new_record = "<tr>" +
                         "<th scope=\"row\" class=\"t-left\"><a href=\"editproduct.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" title=\"Edit this product listing\">" + res.title + "</a></th>" +
                         "<td><a href=\"http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/" + res.asin + "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Visit the Amazon product listing\" >" + res.asin + "</a></td>" +
                         "<td>" + res.sku + "</td>" +
                         "<td>" + res.stock + "</td>" +
                         "<td> £" + res.price + "</td>" +
                         "<td>" + res.live + "</td>" +
                         "</tr>";

            $('#dataResults').append(new_record);
```

I am also returning a value stockUpdated, and i would like to add a class to change the color of the stock table field depending if this comes back true.

I cant remember how i have done this previously but its similar to an if statement

Many thanks in advance.

Alan

Comment: to this bit... "<td>" + res.stock + "</td>" +

Comment: essentially "<td class="updated">" + res.stock + "</td>" +

Comment: Just realized that and deleted that comment before I saw yours

Comment: lol, not a problem :) should of made myself a bit more clear really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can just append the class attribute to the string depending on whether or not your `stockUpdated` property evaluates to true or not:

```
$.each(result, function (index, res) {
    new_record = "<tr>" +
                 "<th scope=\"row\" class=\"t-left\"><a href=\"editproduct.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" title=\"Edit this product listing\">" + res.title + "</a></th>" +
                 "<td><a href=\"http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/" + res.asin + "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Visit the Amazon product listing\" >" + res.asin + "</a></td>" +
                 "<td>" + res.sku + "</td>" +
                 "<td" + (res.stockUpdated ? " class='updated'" : "") + ">" + res.stock + "</td>" +
                 "<td> £" + res.price + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + res.live + "</td>" +
                 "</tr>";

    $('#dataResults').append(new_record);
});
```

I've done it inline with a tertiary conditional just because I like to keep the string concats all together. You could just as easily stop the concatenation at the end of the previous `td` and then wrap a full `if` statement around the next `td`.

Comment: perfect thank you :) now i see it i remember it! will mark as the answer as soon as i can :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and populate it with the class-attribute:

```
var classAttr = (res.StockUpdated) ? "class=\"updated\"" : "";
```

Then you could just do:

```
"<td " + classAttr + ">" + res.stock + "</td>" +
```

Complete example:

```
$.each(result, function (index, res) {
        var classAttr = (res.StockUpdated) ? "class=\"updated\"" : "";
        new_record = "<tr>" +
                     "<th scope=\"row\" class=\"t-left\"><a href=\"editproduct.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" title=\"Edit this product listing\">" + res.title + "</a></th>" +
                     "<td><a href=\"http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/" + res.asin + "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Visit the Amazon product listing\" >" + res.asin + "</a></td>" +
                     "<td>" + res.sku + "</td>" +
                     "<td " + classAttr + ">" + res.stock + "</td>" +
                     "<td> £" + res.price + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + res.live + "</td>" +
                     "</tr>";

        $('#dataResults').append(new_record);
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript. You'll have to call that variable something else.